# What does どうも mean in this sentence?

Tags: words

I can't get why どうも is in the following sentence. What is its role in it?

> **どうも**君は未だ胸に一物もっているような気がする。文句があればはっきり言ってよ。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This どうも means *somehow*. It modifies 気がする at the end of the sentence (i.e., "I somehow feel that ...").

It's the fourth definition of [the entry on jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%82%82) and the second definition of [the entry on デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/156970/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%82%82/).

> ２ 物事の原因や理由がはっきりわからない気持ちを表す。「どうも調子がおかしい」「理数系はどうも苦手だ」